# Is it possible to overwrite a variable?

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, overwrite

Im trying to create link to an object based on it's id. In order to do that I've created list of ID's that I compare to ID of an attribute.

I've tried adding attributes ID to variable, and then compare it, but in the foreach the variable always appears as the same value.

```
                <s:if test="%{#attr.documentRow.buyRequest != null }">
                    <c:forEach items="${liveBuyRequestsId}" var="item">
                        <c:set var="liveBuyId" value="${attr.documentRow.buyRequest.id}"/>
                        <s:if test="%{attr.documentRow.buyRequest.id eq item}">
                            <s:url var="buyRequestUrl" action="buy-request-view-view" includeParams="none">
                                <s:param name="buyRequestId">${attr.documentRow.buyRequest.id}</s:param>
                                <s:param name="previousAction">${attr.buyRequestPreviousAction}</s:param>
                            </s:url>
                        </s:if>
                            <s:url var="buyRequestUrl" action="buy-request-view-history" includeParams="none">
                                <s:param name="buyRequestId">${attr.documentRow.buyRequest.id}</s:param>
                                <s:param name="changeId">${attr.documentRow.buyRequest.changeId}</s:param>
                                <s:param name="previousAction">${attr.buyRequestPreviousAction}</s:param>
                            </s:url>
                        <s:a href="%{buyRequestUrl}">
                            ${liveBuyRequestsId} (${item} by ${attr.documentRow.buyRequest.domainHolder})
                        </s:a>
                    </c:forEach>
                </s:if>
            </display:column>
```

I expect it to create urls based on these statements, but variable "liveBuyId" has always value of the first record that matches

## attr.documentRow.buyRequest != null

Answer (score 0):

Use `item` which is the current/last value

```
<c:set var="liveBuyId" value="${item}"/>
```